# Morph analyser for english

Tags: nlp, morphological-analysis

I want to extract gender,number, person of nouns and pronouns in english. I need a tool to run on linux operating system. Could you please help me finding the tool.

Thanks,
Hemanth

Answer (score 1):

I know two tools for morphological analysis: sfst [1] and mate-tools [2].

[1]https://code.google.com/p/cistern/wiki/SFST

[2]https://code.google.com/p/mate-tools/